Why are some names left untranslated in these English versions of Rulfo's short stories?
I've been reading George D. Schade's English translation of Juan Rulfo's The Burning Plain and Other Stories, which is freely available to borrow from the Internet Archive. In some stories, there are characters whose nicknames are left in Spanish rather than being translated:

"that woman called La Tambora" (The Drum?) and the cow "La Serpentina" (The Serpentine?) in the story "We're very poor";
the brothers "Los Cuatros" (The Four?) and "La Perra" (The Bitch?) and "El Pichón" (The Pigeon?) in the story "The burning plain";

Why were these names left in Spanish rather than being translated? To me as a non-Spanish-speaker, La Tambora looks like it could be someone's actual name, rather than what presumably sounds in the original like a funny nickname, and I don't even know if La Perra is as insulting as "The Bitch" would be in English. Is the same choice made in other translations? How does it affect the impression of these characters?

Note: I'm aware of the previous post Translation: Why are parts of the original language kept? but I feel it's worth asking a question about Rulfo's stories in particular, in case it can be answered more specifically. The original revision of this question asked about only one story, "We're very poor", but given that the language, setting, and author are the same for everything in The Burning Plain and Other Stories, I think it makes sense to ask about these stories together.

"La Tambora looks like it could be someone's actual name": Mr. Tambourine Man sends his regards!

George D. Schade died in 2010, so he is unfortunately not available for comment. However, a newer translation by Doug Weatherford was released in 2024, and it seems that he took the same attitude as Schade: proper names (see this extract for example) have not been translated. Prof. Weatherford is very much alive and kicking, and so I wrote to him to ask why he made this choice.
In his reply he first pointed to a comment he made in the translator's note:

"English-speaking readers may miss potential connotations of a
particular nickname (e.g., La Tambora in “Because We’re So Poor”), but
attempts to choose an equivalent in English, I believe, feel contrived
and are typically more distracting than beneficial."

This seems clear enough, and he went on to expand further:

Others may disagree, but I (and many others) are simply unconvinced
that translating such items into English is the right thing to do.
There’s loss either way, of course. Someone might not understand the
sexual connotation inherent in the nickname “La Tambora,” while
translating such words might force one interpretation over others...
Ultimately, I felt, as a general rule, that sobriquets should be left
in their original language for readers to grasp at potential meanings,
much like readers in the original Spanish will do.

Although this is a personal statement from one translator, I think that it probably reflects a widespread belief among translators.
Finally, "la perra" is a fairly mild insult (although its impact is changing, probably due to American cultural pressure), certainly more mild than "bitch" in English. To more accurately capture the sense of "bitch", you would rather say "zorra" (vixen) instead.

What is "the sexual connotation inherent in the nickname “La Tambora,”"?

As usual, most things literary are a matter of opinion. But I do agree with him there.
